# ADuC845 Eval. Board input signal not reading?

Tags: microcontroller, analog, device

```
#include<ADuC845.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
unsigned int ADC_array[400], ADC_array_aux[400];
float frekans, frekans_aux;
float Vref = 5.145, Vref_aux = 5.025;
int i, j, k, V;
int zero_indexes[50], zero_indexes_aux[50];
sbit LED = 0x0B4;
double rms, rms_aux;
int ilk_sifir_gecis, son_sifir_gecis;

void serial_init()
{
    T3CON = 0x81;                   // timer 3
    T3FD  = 0x12;                   // 38400 baud
    SCON  = 0x52;               // T3CON=81 (38400baud), T3CON=82 (19200baud), 
    T3CON=83 (9600baud)
}                   

void ADC_init()
{
    ADC0CON1 = 0x87;                // Buffer Bypass, Bipolar, +-2.56V
    SF       = 0x03;                // ADC rate = 1365.33Hz         
    ADC0CON2 = 0x40;                // Refin+/-, Ain1-Aincom
    printf("%3.3f V\n",ADC0CON2);
    ADC1CON = 0x41;             // Refin+/-, Bipolar, Ain2-Aincom (AUXILIARY ADC)
    printf("***************************\n");
    printf("\nADCs calibration START\n");
    ADCMODE  = 0x74;                // Offset calibration
    ADCMODE  = 0x75;                // Gain calibration
    printf("ADCs calibration OK\n");
    printf("***************************\n");
    ADCMODE  = 0x3B;                // Continuous conv, Chopping DISABLE, Notch DISABLE, Primary ADC, Auxiliary ADC
}

unsigned int ADC_read()
{
    unsigned int ADC = 0;
    while(! RDY0){}                     // Wait for RDY0 = 1
    ADC = ADC0H*0x10000+ADC0M*0x100+ADC0L;      // ADC data  
    RDY0 = 0;                       // clear ready bit
    return ADC; 
} 

unsigned int Aux_ADC_read()
{
    unsigned int ADC = 0;
    while(! RDY1){}                 // Wait for RDY0 = 1
    ADC = ADC1H*0x100+ADC1M;        // ADC data  
    RDY1 = 0;                   // clear ready bit
    return ADC; 
} 

void main (void)
{
    serial_init();          // Configure serial port for 38400 Baud
    ADC_init();         // Configure ADC
    while(1) {
        ADCMODE  = 0x3B;            // Continuous conv, Chopping DISABLE, Notch DISABLE, Primary ADC, Auxiliary ADC
        for(i=1;i<400;i++)
        {
            ADC_array[i] = ADC_read();
            ADC_array_aux[i] = Aux_ADC_read();
        }

 /**** Sending received data to terminal ****/
        for(i=1;i<400;i++)
        {
            printf("%X %X\n",ADC_array[i], ADC_array_aux[i]);
            V = ((5.0/65536)*ADC_array[i])-2.5;
            printf("%3.3f V\n",V);
        }
 /****** Finding Zero Transitions and Frequency ******/
        j = 0; k = 0;

        for(i=1;i<51;i++)
            zero_indexes[i] = 0;
        zero_indexes_aux[i] = 0;

        for(i=1;i<400;i++)
        {
        if((ADC_array[i]<0x8000 && ADC_array[i+1]>0x8000) || (ADC_array[i]>0x8000 && ADC_array[i+1]<0x8000))
        {
            j++;
            zero_indexes[j] = i;
        }
        if((ADC_array_aux[i]<0x8000 && ADC_array_aux[i+1]>0x8000) || (ADC_array_aux[i]>0x8000 && ADC_array_aux[i+1]<0x8000))
        {
            k++;
            zero_indexes_aux[k] = i;
        }
    }
    frekans = (1365.33/2)*((j-1.0)/(zero_indexes[j]-zero_indexes[1]));
    frekans_aux = (1365.33/2)*((k-1.0)/(zero_indexes_aux[k]-zero_indexes_aux[1]));
/*******************************************************/

/*************** Finding RMS Values ***************/
    rms = 0;
    ilk_sifir_gecis = zero_indexes[1];
    son_sifir_gecis = zero_indexes[j];
    for(i=ilk_sifir_gecis;i<son_sifir_gecis+1;i++)
        rms = rms + pow((((Vref/65536)*ADC_array[i])-(Vref/2)),2);
    rms = sqrt(rms/(son_sifir_gecis - ilk_sifir_gecis + 1));
    rms_aux = 0;
    ilk_sifir_gecis = zero_indexes_aux[1];
    son_sifir_gecis = zero_indexes_aux[k];
    for(i=ilk_sifir_gecis;i<son_sifir_gecis+1;i++)
    rms_aux = rms_aux + pow((((Vref_aux/65536)*ADC_array_aux[i])-(Vref_aux/2)),2);
    rms_aux = sqrt(rms_aux/(son_sifir_gecis - ilk_sifir_gecis + 1));
 /*******************************************************/

/******** Bulunan değerlerin Terminale basılması *******/
    printf("\nVRMS = %2.4f V VRMS_aux = %2.4f V Ratio Error (%%) = %2.3f\nFrekans = %2.1f Hz Frekans_aux = %2.1f Hz\n",rms,rms_aux,100*(rms_aux-rms)/rms,frekans,frekans_aux);
    LED ^= 1;
 /*******************************************************/
}
```

}

**I have ADuc845 Evaluation Board and i didn't see any input values at the terminal can anyone help me**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You code is realy hard to read. But I guess the problem (at least one) is here:

```
    for(i=1;i<51;i++)
        zero_indexes[i] = 0;
    zero_indexes_aux[i] = 0;
```

I guess you want to write:

```
    for(i=1;i<51;i++)
    {
        zero_indexes[i] = 0;
        zero_indexes_aux[i] = 0;
    }
```

A tip: Always use brackets and of course correct identation!